# Import data with CSV file, Don't know how to build task 'csv:import_movies'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I am trying to populate my database with a CSV file. I have looked for other questions on SO and after trying everything I am stuck and was able come up with this:

```
# lib/tasks/import.rake
require 'csv'

desc 'Import Movies'
namespace :csv do
  task :import_movies => [:environment] do
    csv_file = '#{Rails.root}/lib/data/movie.csv'

    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
      Movie.create! ({
        name: row[0],
        url: row[1],
        year: row[2],
        description: row[3],
        genre: row[4]
        })
    end

    # this was also a method others were recommending so I saved it
    #CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
      #Movie.create!(row.to_hash)
    #end

  end
end
```

But when I run `rake csv:import_movies` I get this error running `rake csv:import_movies --trace`

```
rake aborted!                                                                                   
Don't know how to build task  'csv:import_movies'                                                                        
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in`[]'                                                                 
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'                                                                              
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'                                                            
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'                                                                                     
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'                                                                       
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'                                                                         
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'                                                                                
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'                                                                              
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'                                                              
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'                                                                                      
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top(required)>'             
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'                                                                                     
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'                                                                                   
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'                                                                                     
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

And I also tried doing it using this method

```
# db/seeds.rb
require 'csv'

csv_file_path = '#{Rails.root}/lib/data/movie.csv'
File.open(csv_file_path) do |movies|
  movies.read.each_line do |movie|
    title, url, year, description, genre = movie.chomp.split(",")
    Movie.create!( name: title, url: url, year: year, description: decription, genre: genre )           
  end
end
```

And then ran `rake db:seed --trace` and then I got an error again which was:

```
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)                                                                               
** Execute db:seed                                                                                    
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)                                                                               
** Invoke environment (first_time)                                                                               
** Execute environment                                                                                
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
```

I ran `rake db:migrate:status` and got this, which is weird and I haven't come across before:

```
Status   Migration ID    Migration Name                                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------                                         
up     20140407094349  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                                 
up     20140407094355  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                                 
up     20140407094405  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                                 
up     20140409112119  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                                 
up     20140409113144  ********** NO FILE **********
```

I hope someone has experience with this as this is my first time attempting to use rake and csv files in Rails. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if run `rake -T` `task csv:import_movies` have in list?

Comment: @PhilidorGreen I just ran `rake -T` and it wasn't in the list.

Comment: You need to add a `desc "whatever"` above the `namespace` in your rake task to be able to see it with `rake -T`.

Answer (score 1):

try renaming your rake file to - 'csv.rake' and remove the [] around :environment

also put the description inside of the :namespace